# Angular 4 ng build: is --aot automatically executed with --prod?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I wonder if there's a difference between

```
ng build --prod
```

and

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

The file sizes remain the same for me. Is `--aot` selected automatically if you specify `--prod`?

Comment: 1. Which version of the CLI. 2. What does the wiki page say? 3. Also you could test this yourself by seeing what happens with `--aot false`.

Comment: if you are using the latest stable build `ng build --prod` is enough . it includes `aot` . you need not specify the `--aot` tag explicity

Comment: AoT is getting more implemented by Angular it's more like a default right now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Thanks for the advise with `--aot false`. It is interesting that with `--aot false` the file main.bundle.js is smaller than with `--aot true`. Anyway question was answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest Stable version of CLI you need not use the `--aot` flag the `--prod flag` enables it by default.

For more info check this [**LINK**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds)

[image]